# Why does exporting a file in adobe audition reduce the desired length?

Tags: noise-reduction, adobe-audition, exporting

I am trying to reduce an audio noise in adobe audition. I do the noise reduction but when i export the file, the audio length is about 5 seconds shorter. And i cannot sync it with my video anymore.

I put both original and edited file in the timeline, and sync the begining, but at the end of the files there is a lot delay between them.

I tried to just open the file in audition and export it without any editing. And it still does the same thing. So it is just about the export not the editing and noise reduction.

The original file length is 32:12
The new length is 32:07

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you possibly have set up a project in Audition at the wrong sampling rate. Make sure that you are fully aware of the sampling rate of all the audio you are using and that the project sampling rate matches.